# How can I use a Spring HttpRequest in my controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-test

I've set up my test this way

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@RunWith( SpringRunner.class )
public class PublicControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;
```

this is my controller signature

```
@GetMapping( produces = MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE )
ResponseEntity<ResourceSupport> index( final HttpRequest request ) {
```

now it seems to be injecting a proxy value, but if you call `request.getURI()` for example, it seems to be null.

I'm trying to do this so I can pass request to `UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpRequest(  )`, which is called by previous `linkTo` methods in my controller and they aren't getting a proxy/null.

How can I get HttpRequest? (note: I don't want/can't use `HttpServletRequest` which gets passed fine but is not the right interface for `UriComponentsBuilder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I can use the `HttpServletRequest`

```
@GetMapping( produces = MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE )
ResponseEntity<ResourceSupport> index( final HttpServletRequest request ) {
```

but it has to be wrapped? by `ServletServerHttpRequest` to get the interface I want.

```
HttpRequest httpRequest = new ServletServerHttpRequest( request )
```